# Strategy to develop using sql lite on OSX, and easily swap to Sql server for production

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Is it possible to develop a dotnetcore application on OSX using a simple database like sqlite for development, and then for real production use sql server?

I will be using entity framework as my database layer.   I have a OSX laptop but the client will be running this on windows and sql server.

Is this a safe strategy or there are other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is the answer to all such questions.  You shouldn't have to swap out technologies between environments.

[Run SQL Server container images with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash)